Measurably parametrized conditional expectation
Let $(X,\mathcal{F})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{G})$ be measurable spaces, not necessarily standard Borel.
Consider $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the Borel sigma-algebra $\mathcal{B}$, and take a family of measurably parametrized probability measures (Markov kernel) $p_x$ on $Y$, indexed by $x\in X$.
Let now $f:(Y,\mathcal{G})\to(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ be integrable, and take a sub-sigma-algebra $\mathcal{S}\subseteq\mathcal{G}$. Can we pick conditional expectations $\mathbb{E}_{p_x}[f|\mathcal{S}]$, relative to the measure $p_x$, in a way that's measurable in $x$?
More precisely, is there a measurable function $g:(X,\mathcal{F})\times (Y,\mathcal{S})\to(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ such that for all $S\in\mathcal{S}$ and for all $x\in X$,
$$
\int_{S} g(x,y)\,p_x(dy) \;=\; \int_{S} f(y)\,p_x(dy) \quad ?
$$
